# threejs personal uvs dont work when i change texture

Tags: three.js, texture-mapping, render-to-texture

When I load the model with a custom uvs in the JavaScript it's working fine when I load the model:

```
var loader=new THREE.JSONLoader();
    loader.load(
    name .js',
    function ( geometry, materials ) {
        var material = new THREE.MeshFaceMaterial( materials );
        var object = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
        object.position.y = -10;
        object.name = name; 
        view3D.scene.add( object );
    }, onProgress, onError)
```

I create a new texture with:

```
function CreateTextureMaterial(ImageName){
    var Texture = new THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture('texture/'+ImageName); 
    var Material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ 
    map:Texture});
    return Material;
}
```

and I load it on the model:

```
function ChangeTexture(ObjectName, TextureMaterial){
    obj = scene.getObjectByName(ObjectName);
    obj.material = TextureMaterial;
}
```

It doesn't work as I expect - it loads with default uvs set but not the one of the file. I tried to use:

```
var obj = scene.getObjectByName(ObjectName);
var Texture = new THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture('texture/'+ImageName); 
var Material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ 
map:obj.geomerty.faceVertexUvs});
obj.material=Material;
```

after I cant see anything. What do I need to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because `MeshFaceMaterial` is kinda collection of materials, and not the same as just a single material such as an instance of MeshBasicMaterial.

Also, you have to apply **image** texture for `map`.

You can do like this instead.

`var texture = new THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture('texture/'+ImageName); 
var myBasicMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
  map: texture
});
obj.material.materials[ 0 ] = myBasicMaterial;`

Comment: it works fine! but the material i need to change is 
obj.material.materials[ 1 ]

Comment: now your answer is ok for 1 object in a scene, but in case of multiple object i need to understand wich materials number is show by default.
example
obj1.material.materials[0] = Material; //it is ok
obj2.material.materials[0] = Material; //it shown not the visible layer